# using css transform scale on element positioned using translateY

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, frontend

Front-end developers have little recourse but to use css `transform: translateY(-50%)` with `top: 50%` to vertically center elements of variable height. I'm doing this for a slide show of images that I want to be able to zoom in on. I've been trying to animate this using `transform: scale(x)` but of course any transform values applied to an element will overwrite any other ones that came before. So, to preserve `transform: translateY(-50%)` value while also running `animate( transform: 'scale(2.5)' )`I've instead run `animate( transform: 'translateY(-50%) scale(2.5)' )`. However, in all cases I've noticed that same curious result. The first time I trigger the animation it simply resets the translate values to nothing, and then on subsequent runs it toggles the following transform values on and off:

first state:

```
-webkit-transform: translate(0px, -50px) rotate(0rad) skewX(0rad) scale(1, 1);
```

second state:

```
-webkit-transform: translate(0px, -125px) rotate(0rad) skewX(0rad) scale(2.5, 2.5);
```

On thing that's clear is my reset translateY value somehow gets reinterpreted to pixels before being multiplied by the same factor as the scale.

Here's the code. For a little more content, the slideshow has a property draggable that I am toggling on and off in concert with enabling the zoom since I think having them work simultaneously would be terrible for UX.

```
$('.activate-zoom').click (e) ->
  if $('.slideshow-products').slick('slickGetOption', 'draggable')
    $('.slideshow-products').slick('slickSetOption', 'draggable', false).slick('slickSetOption', 'swipe', false)
    $('.products .slick-active img').animate( 'transform': 'scale(2.5) translateY(-50%)')
  else
    $('.slideshow-products').slick('slickSetOption', 'draggable', true).slick('slickSetOption', 'swipe', true)
    $('.products .slick-active img').animate( 'transform': 'scale(1) translateY(-50%)' )
```

What can I do to prevent the image from first reseting its translateY value, remaining vertically centered, and then zooming given that y-axis baseline.

Comment: As i recall the **order** of the transforms is important...you might want to experiment with that.

Comment: You could NOT use translateY to center the element. Hey Zach :) Or you could try using translate3d(x,y,z), and instead of scale(x) use translateZ(z) to zoom.

Comment: @plondon You can center element vertically with translateY.

Comment: @AndrzejOśmiałowski I just meant that there are other options besides using translateY, not that it's impossible to use translateY. That's why I said could and not can. Sorry for the confusion

Comment: @plondon Clear now :)